# How do I create an interface that allows me to access button(and other ui) functions in C++ implemented using MFC from python?

Tags: python, c++, interface, mfc

I am in the process of creating an automated testing framework in python. I would like to create an architecture that can access ui functions that are called below the ui layer in C++, using python. I am struggling to bridge this gap.

Comment: 1 option is to use sockets on both ends.

Comment: Unclear, what you're asking, but you're probably looking for [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score -1):

If [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) is an option, just create a .NET assembly with it and use .NET interoperability from within your MFC GUI Framework.

Comment: I am trying to avoid accessing MFC gui framework from .net assembly.

Comment: It's rather the other way around. Can you explain a bit more, why this wouldn't be an option for you? I was assuming that you already have a decent C++ codebase and just want to use Python as a scripting engine within your MFC testing application -- or what is the reason you want to mix up these two worlds? What kind of GUI do you have in mind? Why did you decide not to use wxPython for example? What GUI functions do you want to manipulate from Python?